# Make all the vertical separators in the same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, navbar

I have a Bootstrap navbar with few links in it, and verical separators between them. The problem is that when the screen width is between ~1100px - ~770px the separators are not having the same height. here is their css code:

```
 .navbar-default li + li {
    background:url('../images/buffer1.png') no-repeat top right;
    background-size: auto 90%;

}
```

I guess it's because of the use of percentage, but I have to use it due to the responsive design (when the screen get smaller the `li's` width is changing and the separator have to fit to their height...

Here is live example:

http://www.bootply.com/KuD2TuYe0H

I'm looking for a solution (CSS only is better) that make all the separator with the same height.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to fart around with bottom margin/padding. Works in IE7+.

```
.navbar .nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
}

.navbar .nav > li {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    direction: rtl;
    width: calc(100% / 7.0);
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d4; */
}

.nav > li {
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #777;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Comment: The HTML is in the example